# [Py 2/3 migration]: How to verify class method type in py3?

Tags: python

During the py2/3 migration process, our test harness spotted the following issue:

```py
import types;

class Test(object):
  def foo(self):
    class InnerClass(object):
      def innerFn():
        pass

    innerInst = InnerClass()

    instanceRef = isinstance(innerInst.innerFn, types.MethodType)
    classRef = isinstance(InnerClass.innerFn, types.MethodType)

    print(type(innerInst.innerFn)) # py3: <class 'method'>
    print(type(InnerClass.innerFn) # py3: <class 'function'>
    # in py2: both are <type 'instancemethod'>

    assert(instanceRef) # succeeds in py2 and py3
    assert(classRef) # fails in py3 but succeeds in py2
```

What is the recommended way to identify both class and instance method types in py3? The original source code has the following check that is causing the issue:

```py
target = getTarget() # target can be either class method or instance method ref
if isinstance(target, types.MethodType):
  do_something
```

Links to REPL:

- Py2: https://repl.it/@jayzelenkov/innerpy2
- Py3: https://repl.it/@jayzelenkov/innerpy3

Comment: In python3, methods should be normal functions when looked up on the class itself if my memory does not fail me. They become closures on their instance upon instantiation.

Comment: @spectras You're correct. Unfortunately, catching all functions is too permissive in this case. I was hoping to find a way to detect class and instance methods only.

Comment: @JayZelenkov there are no classmethods here. To detect a classmethod, you would use `isinstance(obj, classmethod)`

Comment: Good point. What is a proper way to call them? Method reference via class definition and method reference via class instance? In this case, obj is not available, only the method/function reference itself. The goal is not to detect classmethods per se, it is to detect whether or not the function reference is a method (part of the class) or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`InnerClass.innerFn` was never a class method. It was an unbound method object. Unbound method objects no longer exist in Python 3; `InnerClass.innerFn` now resolves to an ordinary function object.

Depending on why you were performing this check, you may not want to treat `InnerClass.innerFn` as a method at all. If you do, you can get something similar **but not equivalent** to the old check by checking the function's `__qualname__`:

```
def check(obj):
    parts = obj.__qualname__.split('.')
    return len(parts) > 1 and not parts[-2].startswith('<')
```

A function's `__qualname__` has at least one `.` in it if it was defined inside a class or another function scope. If it was defined in a function scope, the second-to-last component of the `__qualname__` is usually `<locals>`, but it can also be a few other things like `<listcomp>` or `<genexp>` in the function scope created by a list comprehension, generator expression, or other similar contexts. I'm pretty sure all the function scope cases start with `<`, though, and the class scope cases never do.

This isn't equivalent to the old check if a function was defined outside the class and then set as a class attribute, or in other cases where the `__qualname__` metadata doesn't line up with whether the function was accessed as a class attribute, and I haven't bothered to handle non-function input types.

Comment: Makes sense. In py2, both type(innerInst.innerFn) and type(InnerClass.innerFn) return <type 'instancemethod'>. It was a long shot, but I was hoping there is a way to simulate the old behavior. Thanks for the great explanation!